# Logging in with Facebook via the app is using a different account

Tags: bug, android-app, facebook

When I tried to login using Facebook on my mobile browser I generated a new account as it used my Facebook photo, but on the app I chose login using Facebook and the app chose to use a different account.

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: ZTE
- Device Model: Z832

  - OS Version: 6.0.1 (20160425.181859)